# selecting area on photo

Tags: javascript, select, area

is there any free JS library to select custom resize area on photo?

Comment: Is the requirement for re size or crop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)** is a nice one which uses jQuery.

[Examples and Demos](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)